# ng-walkthrough directive for multiple pages

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js for my project. I want to show tour guide for my project which goes through multiple pages and show next step on next button click. 
I use ng-walkthrough for single page tour-- 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-walkthrough

But not getting proper example to make all tour steps in flow and goes through multiple pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for angularjs touring i use ui-tour http://benmarch.github.io/angular-ui-tour/#/docs instead of ng-walkthrough.
This one i found better option as per my requirement.